# Updating eigen-decomposition of symmetric matrix $A$ to eigendecomposition of $A+D$ where $D$ is low-rank diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ and a mostly-zeros non-negative diagonal matrix $D$, is there a way to cheaply update the eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors of $A$ to that of $A+D$? Ideally I'm looking for something akin to the Woodbury matrix identity.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34252/eigenvalues-of-ab-where-a-is-symmetric-positive-definite-and-b-is-diagonal

Comment: When describing diagonal matrix $D$ as "mostly-zeros", do you mean this is true of the diagonal entries?  E.g. a single nonzero entry on the diagonal would be of interest?

Comment: hardmath: Yes, $D$ is a diagonal matrix and even its diagonal is just mostly zeros.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend reading http://www.unige.ch/~gander/consulting/X/EigenUpdate.ps.gz and having a look at the cited work of **Golub and Van Loan**.
They show howto update matrices with rank-one-changes. You can understand your update matrix $D \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as a sum of $n$ rank-one-updates.
Good luck!